# How to separate source code in svn/git/hg?

Tags: version-control

Our development team have following source code and must separate the ownership.

```
/common/ (owner:all, reviewer:all)
/prj_A/A1 (owner:King, reviewer:Queen)
/prj_A/A2 (owner:Queen, reviewer:King)
/prj_B/B1 (Owner:Princess, reviewer:Prince)
/prj_B/B2 (Owner:Prince, reviewer:Princess)
```

For prj_A, they must check out command & prj_A to build and test.
For prj_B, they must check out command & prj_B to build and test.
The code on different project can not viewed by the other team.

So, what's proper setting on svn/git/hg?  Will you plan to use multiple repository to store these code?

Answer (score 0):

> Will you plan to use multiple repository to store these code?

For a DVCS (Distributed VCS), yes: each repository should not include "everything" and should represent a coherent set of files, in order to allow to clone only what you need (instead of cloning "the all world" all the time).
You don't have that issue with a CVCS like SVN, where you can keep everything in the same repo.

> So, what's proper setting on svn/git/hg?

- For Git, you need to add an **[authorization layer](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/auth.html)** like [gitolite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/index.html#what).
- Mercurial would use **[hg serve](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#serve)**: see "[Is there anything like svnserve for Mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771379/is-there-anything-like-svnserve-for-mercurial)", and also "[Authorizing Users](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AuthorizingUsers)".

Comment: Do you mean, I should separate each directory for git/hg?
Or, just separate as common,prj_A,prj_B?

Comment: @DanielYCLin one repo per project, not per directory, unless you really have strong confidentiality issue (where one directory shouldn't be visible by another team): you can render a (DVCS) repo non-accessible by another team through authorization layer, but not a directory: you are always cloning the *full* repo.